# Is there any cool and simple project for learning Gitflow for beginners?

Tags: maven, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I'm new to Git and Maven, going to deliver a presentation about Gitflow and versioning control with maven plugin, I wanted to add a cool&simple project (python&Jupyter Notebook/java&intelliJ) as an example in the end, but not sure how to do this, anyone has any thoughts? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You know that Maven is intended for Java and not for python?

Comment: Hi I know, I've edited my question. @khmarbais